# Quick find and replace a fixed placeholder

Tags: key-bindings, substitute

I have a config file that have placeholder `PKG`, in workflow, I need to replace this `PKG` with a string but typing `:%s/blah/blah/g` cost time.

I need a quick map key that asks for a string to replace then replace all `PKG` with that string.

Can vim do that? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
nnoremap <KEY> :%s/PKG//g<Left><Left>
```

It populates the command line with `:%s/PKG//g` with the cursor between `//`. You can then simply type the new string and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I just need that, a wrapper would overkill.

Comment: May want to add `:keeppatterns` to avoid adding `/PKG/` to the search history. See `:h :keeppatterns`